# Cache clear probem in Larave

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, caching

I have a problem. I am download project from hosting. now when I run the project this error shows.
[pic attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbJ2R.png).
I think this is cache problem, I clear cache, view, but still same issue.

Comment: Please provide more info. A screenshot and a comment that you tried clear cache doesn't help. What are `the exact` commands you ran? Did you download the project with all dependancies or only the git version?

Comment: Project download with all depedancies.
run these commands
`php artisan cache:clear` `php artisan view:clear` `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: `laravel-5` or `laravel-8`? Which project did you download? Followed their installation instructions? Did you make sure that the method actually exists?

Comment: `laravel-5` and this method is exist. Project is live without any issue but this issue on local.

Comment: your adminiy() undefined error share your code.

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have installed composer,

now run this command and see:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: still same issue

Comment: make sure adminiy() function exists then, and if you are saying on live this working, find that function on live server and check on local files.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the **vendor** directory and **composer.cache** file from project root and hit the following commands.

```
composer install
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan serve
```

Through these, you can also check if there is any composer-related issue.